# Is there some free remote sniffer (aka sniffer on free remote server)?

Tags: security, http, packages, packet-sniffer

I have this setup:

```
                                    ________Company LAN_______
 _________                     .  '|              _________
|         |                       .| BUNCH OF    |         |
| Server1 |-->                  .  | SECURITY    | MyHost  |
|_________|                       .|             |_________|
                               .   |__________________________
```

My **main objective** is to see what packages `Server1` sends.

`Server1` sends periodically packets to a specified `target IP` that I can change. If I set `MyHost` as the target IP and use Wireshark, I won't be able to capture anything because of the company's firewall.

For that reason I need a Server outside of the company which runs a sniffer or something, like in the pic below:

```
                                    ________Company LAN_______
 _________         _________       |              _________
|         |       |         |      | BUNCH OF    |         |
| Server1 |--->---| Server2 |      | SECURITY    | MyHost  |
|_________|       |_________|      |             |_________|
                       |           |__________________|_______
                       '------------------------------'
```

Does something like that exist? Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, there is. No, we do not recommend a service or product here. Good ASCII art, btw. - I like it.

Comment: @TomTom Yes, and I apologize. But I have no idea where else to ask..

Comment: @TomTom I wonder why you cannot recommend a solution for the OP's problem?

Comment: `tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -Uw file.pcap`

Comment: @Pat Because the solution is not as simple as your simplified case answer and besides the rules of this site not allowing software/service recommendations. heck, copying this is something i could do on any step in my network with a router command. But I do not know the OPs exact scenario and will not give - as you - a totally wrong answer.

Comment: @TomTom thanks for editing your previous post and removing the included disrespectful terms. Now I'm challenging you to prove here why mine is "a totally wrong answer" as you said. I really think yours are just big words w/o any supporting fact.

Answer (score 1):

Remote sniffing with Wireshark is one alternative

Running i.e. rpcapd in Server2 capturing its received traffic and you remotely running
wireshark from MyHost.

[image: Wireshark Capture Options]

Of course the communication between the remote capture daemon and your Wireshark has to clear your security layer.

Comment: Which Wireshark version is that? I don't see the remote option on Wireshark 1.10.6.

Comment: @kasperd ; sorry I just took a picture corresponding to an old version of wireshark; please see now included the one that corresponds to v 1.10.5

Comment: I found the `Interface Management` window already, but it only has the first two tabs `Pipes` and `Local Interfaces`. The `Remote Interfaces` tab simply isn't there.

Comment: check your version; "Remote Interfaces" is there https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapManageInterfacesSection.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a nifty service in the end

http://requestb.in

It's pretty much a sniffer for HTTP messages. Since `Server1` in my case sends HTTP messages, this service worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

A nice (free) application is NTOPNG http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/ (earlier NTOP) which I am using for years already. With this application you can add "probes" in your network and gather this data in a centralised way.

However, this application does not give you deep level info like Wireshark, but it is a great way to track network traffic and analyse which packets were sent by whom (in case you use e.g. a span-port).

NTOP is available for a lot of linux distributions. (e.g. apt-get install ntop)